# Typescript throws no error when calling a function which expects (spread) arguments

Tags: typescript

In Typescript 4.0.3 I would expect an error when I try to call a function which spreads params.
The Code below does not throw an error (and tsc compiles it), but it obviously fails because there is no array to reduce.

Is my Code wrong or is this a problem with the spread operator?

calc.ts

```js
export function substract(...a: number[]):number {
  return a.reduce((acc, val) => acc - val);
}
```

main.ts

```js
import { substract } from "./calc.js";

console.log(substract()); // Should display an error
console.log(substract(1)); // Works fine
console.log(substract(2,1)); // Works fine
```

Comment: It doesn't fail because there's no array, it fails because it's an *empty* array and you don't provide an initial value. But that's a runtime problem, not a compile time one.

Comment: "*// Should display an error*" - it's normally perfectly fine to call variadic functions with no input. It means that you get an empty array. You could specify "at least one parameter"  but I think the bigger problem is your code not handling empty arrays, rather than a problem with the signature.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, my mistake here, I tried it in the dev-console and didn't expect ... "empty argument" to result in []. Also the sentence with runtime problem makes sense, since I'm using ts-jest it immediately resulted in a failed test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript can't access and doesn't know about the values you pass on runtime. But one thing you can do is specify your function parameter type so that it doesn't accept empty arrays.

```
type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]]

function substract(...a: NonEmptyArray<number>): number { 
  return a.reduce((acc, val) => acc - val);
}

console.log(substract()); // Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0.
console.log(substract(1)); // Works fine
console.log(substract(2,1)); // Works fine
```

Depending on the functionality of your `subtract` function, it maybe is appropriate to handle empty array parameter in your function body. something like this would be fine for instance:

```
function substract(...a: number[]): number { 
  if (!a.length) throw Error("Expected a non empty array!") // or return 0 (whatever your logic is)
  return a.reduce((acc, val) => acc - val);
}
```